# Converting circular structure to JSON .send html value to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, editor

I use editor in my page when i want to update my values with ajax i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

this is my view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#editor").kendoEditor({
                value: "@Html.Raw(Model.Content)"
            });
            $("#back").click(function () {
                $.get('@Url.Action("Index", "Editor")', { siteId: "@ViewBag.SiteId", widgetId: "@Model.WidgetId" },
                              function (data) {
                                  $("div[data-role='popup']").remove();
                                  var indexContent = $(data).find("#content");
                                  $(indexContent).fadeIn(101);
                                  $("#content").replaceWith(indexContent);
                              });


            });
            var content = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
            $("#save").click(function () {
                var editor = {
                    Id: 1,
                    Content: content,
                    Title: 1,
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Editor")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json charset=UTF-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(editor),

                });
    });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="editorContainer">
        <div id="editorContent">
            <input type="text"  value="@Model.Title" style="width:300px" id="title"/>
            <textarea id="editor" rows="10" cols="30" style="width: 740px; height: 440px">
</textarea>
        </div>


    </div>
    <button id="save">ذخیره</button>
    <button id="back">بازگشت</button>
</body>
</html>
```

in my view i post value with jquery ajax but i get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
saveButton.click(function () {
                var model = {
                    Id: '@Model.Id',
                    Content: editor.data("kendoEditor").encodedValue(),
                    Title: $('#title').val(),
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Editor")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json charset=UTF-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ editor: model, siteId: '@ViewBag.siteId' }),
                        success: function () {
                            alert('تغییرات مورد نظر با موفقیت اعمال شد.');
                            //window.parent.document.location.replace('@Url.Action("SiteIndex", "Editor")?' + parametrs);
                         },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('متاسفانه خطایی در سیستم رخ داد،دوباره تلاش کنید.');
                    }
                });
            });
```

this is right

Answer (score 1):

You cannot JSON serialize object hierarchies containing circular references. This simply isn't supported by the JSON format. You should use view models and break the circular dependency that exists in your objects.